# retrieve user credentials from firebase phone authentication

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my code, after users verify their phone number using firebase phone authentication and verification, users will be redirected to the registration screen to fill their information. These information doesn't include phone number because its not a good practice to ask for phone number again from UX wise.

Then users will submit their information and it will be stored to firestore database.

In my user model I have to store the phone number also which I didn't ask for in the registration form, it only exists in the user authentication credentials. Following function is how I store data:

```
void storeData() async {
    final ap = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    UserModel userModel = UserModel(
      name: nameController.text,
      email: emailController.text.trim(),
      province: dropDownValue.trim(),
      dateOfBirth: dateController.text.trim(),
      challengeHistory: [],
      challengeMember: [],
      uid: _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid,
      phone: //Here I want to retrieve phone number,
    );
    ap.saveUserDataToFirebase(
      context: context,
      userModel: userModel,
      onSuccess: () {
        ap.saveUserDataToSP().then(
              (value) => ap.setSignIn().then(
                    (value) => Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
                        ),
                        (route) => false),
                  ),
            );
      },
    );
  }
```

as seen in the code am not sure how to retrieve the user's phone number to store it in the firestore database, ill appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `_firebaseAuth` is an object of type `FirebaseAuth`. The `User` has a `phoneNumber` field, you can find that in the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/c20e83aca4f0078cedad0935eeb848f8f73c8b37/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/user.dart#L57).

The code below should work correctly:

```
phone: _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.phoneNumber,
```

Comment: Thanks Vitali simply solved my problem